# What does "strap input" mean as applied to the DS90UB960WRTDRQ1?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, mipi, digital-input

I am using a [DS90UB960WRTDRQ1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds90ub960-q1.pdf?ts=1700634942834&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) in my design. In the pinout functions the definitions of the I/O pins are given as shown below:

[image]

What does "strap input" mean? What is the difference between a strap input and a general input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't focus on pin being called a strap.

Look what the strap pins do in the table.

IDX and MODE are the only pins called strap pins, and these select the I2C address and operation mode of the chip when it starts up.

The word could be changed from strap pin to configuration pin.

You can also use find feature of your PDF reader to search for the word "strap" and you find more info on what strap pins are, what they do, and how to use them.

Many chips call these initial mode and configuration pins as straps.

It may also be related to "bootstrapping" - there might be a MCU hidden inside.

The "strap" might relate to the fact that you need to "tie" the pin to a certain logic state, or in this case, as they are analog input pins, to a certain voltage level (within tolerance) to start the chip in the operating mode you want.

Answer (score 2):

Difference between strap and general input is that strap don't change during operation, it's fixed.

**Example** *page 28, 7.4.3 MODE Pin*
Rx mode is set by a voltage divider for the operation you want.

Comment: I don't think so. Many MCUs have strap pins to configure in which mode it boots, and you sure will want to change the strap pins as you wish to boot it normally or boot it into firmware upgrade mode etc.

Comment: It's a matter of how you define it. In the example I'd say it's fixed, although you could desolder those resistors and solder new ones, or even use a potentiometer. There are programmable boot fuses as well, some are permanently done, others can be changed. || I edited my answer to read 'during operation'.

Comment: *"It's a matter of how you define it."* Obviously - that's the entire question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a strap input is one that should not be changed while the circuit is powered up.

The can be changed between power-ups to select different configuration or operation of the part, to make it suit the application. Which is why they have an input pin for selection in the first place.

I think the original analogy from decades back is for strapping down parts of a machine before switching it on. In the modern world, you could imagine straps such as seatbelts in cars.

As with any pin function, check carefully the description and detail of it in the datasheet or other documentation before deciding what to do with it.